# Action Bar in Fragments - Tablets and Phones

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am creating an App where I am using Fragments so as to attain UI flexibility.

In the Phone Portrait and Landscape mode the Fragmnets Appears like this : 
[image: Phone Landscape and Portrait]

In Tablets Portrait and Landscape Mode it Appears like this :

[image: Tablets Portrait and Landscape]

My main concern is ACTION BAR. I want to hide action bar only in case of SMARTPHONE in LANDSCAPE mode where FRAGMENT B appears Full Screen.
I want to display the Action Bar in all other cases as I have shown in the Images.

I have searched whole stack overflow but did not find any solution. Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, there are 2 things you need to do:

1. Check if your device is a smartphone or tablet.

Create a new resources folder called `values-sw600dp` inside your `res` folder. (This only works for Android versions  before 3.2, for previous versions create a `values-xlarge` folder)

Then here we create a file and set the following value:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in the standard value file (as res/values/), you set such boolean to false:

false

Now you can check if you are running in a tablet size device:

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
// do a
} else {
// do b
}
```

2. In case of being a smartphone, check orientation and hide action bar.

In your `onCreateView` method in your `fragmentB` after checking if you are using a smartphone or tablet (using your-new-resource-file.xml) we have to check the orientation. If the orientation is LANDSCAPE, then we hide the actionbar.

```
 boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (!tabletSize) 
{
  //Lets check orientation
  if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
  {
      getActivity().getActionBar().hide(); //getSupportActionBar().hide() if using appcompat
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Then, in the standard value file (as res/values/), you set such boolean to false:  ??? What do you mean by this statement? please elaborate?

Comment: I have edited my answer, what I meant is that you have to create multiple new resources files (1 per size folder you might need), inside your res folder (standard folder for resources) you have to define the `isTablet` value to false and in your `sw600dp` folder you have to put it to true.

Comment: I have accepted your answer.. please mark my question as important or up. If u think it is a good question

Answer (score 0):

I have used this codes to check if we are in SMARTPHONE or TABLET :

```
// Function to check if we are inside Phone or Tablet
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {

    Boolean tablet = (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;

    return tablet;

    /* Returns TRUE if we are in TABLET
     * 
     * Returns FALSE if we in PHONE
     * 
     * 
     * */
}
```

Then after if i am inside the phone : I have used following code to check my screen orientation:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
  getActivity().getActionBar().hide(); //getSupportActionBar().hide() if using appcompat Library
}else{
  getActivity().getActionBar().show(); 
}
```

Comment: You should have edited your own question but anyway, I think you should be good to go!